# Query all instance of and subclasses of wd:43229

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I would like to fetch all entities that lead to wd:43229. However, my query, for a particular example (wd:Q95) returns partially correct results and also redundant entities.

```
SELECT  distinct ?subClass ?subClassLabel
WHERE {
 wd:Q95   p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* ?subClass .
  ?subClass p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* ?node .
  ?subClass rdfs:label ?subClassLabel. 
  OPTIONAL {?node p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q43229 }
  FILTER( LANG(?subClassLabel)="en" )
}
```

List of entities required

- business
- technology company
- public company
- juridicial person
- enterprise
- operation
- organizational unit
- public company
- joint-stock company
- limited company
- commercial company
- private company
- company

Any idea how to fix this query?

Comment: why do you put the required pattern into an `OPTIONAL` clause?

Comment: That's because by replacing variable `?node` with `wd:Q43229` produces no results whatsoever